# Storing image in SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, insert

I am trying to store a .png image inside a database using SQL Server 2008. I have done this just fine using mySQL but for some reason it looks like this when placing it into ms SQL Server:

```
0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000003160000031608060000006CBE..etc etc etc
```

The column data type is set to image.

And here is the code I am using to insert it into the system:

```
Dim SQL As String = "" & _
    "INSERT INTO dbo.thelabels (theV, theJID, theK, theS, theDRVorPAS, theImg, insertDayTime)" & _
    "VALUES ('" & theV & "', " & theJID & ", " & theK & ", " & theS & ", '" & theDRVorPAS & "', @img, '" & Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss") & "');"

    myCommandSQL.Connection = connSql
    myCommandSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path))
    myCommandSQL.CommandText = SQL
    myCommandSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connSql.Close()
    myCommandSQL.Dispose()
```

Any help would be great! :)

David

Comment: in MS SQL `image` is not a data type for storing graphical data per se. MS SQL has no built in support for viewing graphical data as a picture. The `image` data type is the legacy format for storing binary data. Use VARBINARY(MAX) but you still won't be able to view it as a picture with the standard MS SQL tools.

Comment: Have you ever heard of **SQL Injection** attacks?? You shouldn't be concatenating together your SQL statements - especially not if any of the input is from a user. You should use **parametrized queries** instead - **ALWAYS**, no excuses.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I'd recommend defining the column as a VARBINARY(MAX) type instead of IMAGE which will be [deprecated in a future version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Secondly, what makes you think it isn't inserting the image properly? If you do the insert and then query that row in SSMS, that is the kind of thing you'll see as the representation of the binary data. You would need more code in .NET to convert that binary data back into an image form at display time. I haven't tried this tool, but might be worth a look to check whether the images have gone in OK - [SQL Image Viewer](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/sqltools/pages/SQL-Image-Viewer-details.aspx).